# JSF prettify/beautify HTML output

Tags: html, jsf

I want to correct indent before I send a JSF page to the user, because the indent is a little bit messy from JSF and it would be easier to do css stylig with nicier indent. So I want to redirect all output written by JSF rendering to a variable, parse it and then send it to the user. I tried to play a little with and thought that the `<f:phaseListener>` listening to RenderPhase might be the right way to go, but I don't know how to do that concretely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is the best tool for the job. A [`PhaseListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) is only interesting if you're interested in intercepting on the JSF lifecycle and/or the JSF component tree, not when you're only interested in its generated HTML response. There exist the [`JTidyFilter`](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html) which does exactly what you want. Just define it once in `web.xml` and all the respone HTML will be prettified. All it basically does is wrapping the `response.getOutputStream()` to haul it through [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) first.

Comment: the JTidy homepage says, that it uses `<filter-class>org.w3c.tidy.servlet.filter.JTidyFilter</filter-class>`, but there are just `org.w3c.tidy` and `org.w3c.tidy.ant` packages in the downloaded jar...?

Comment: Here's the [jtidyservlet.jar](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/nightly/jtidyservlet-r8-SNAPSHOT.jar). It contains the filter as well.